# Insert default values not working mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using mongoose version `5.2.5` and here is the sample model of my order

```
....
let PlaceOrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        any: {}
}, { strict: false },
    { timestamps: { updatedAt: 'last_updated', createdAt: 'created' });
```

I am using the above model in main script with mongoose `save` and `findOneAndUpdate`. 
In our production system , we are seeing many document that does not have `last_updated` key missing in the save document.

Here are sample code of the mongoose `save` method and `findOneAndUpdate` in our main script.We are seeing some of the documents have `updated_at` keys while very few of them does not have it while saving the document

```
let orderModel = require('./orderModel');
let newOrder = {
    order_no: 1234
};

//save usage code
(new Order(newOrder).save({lean: true}, ()=> {

  //do...something

}));

//findOneAndUpdate usage Code
 let orderNo = 123
 OrderModel.findOneAndUpdate({ order_no: orderNo },
                {
                    $set: { items: [{product_id: 'abc', quantity: 1}] },
                }, 
                { new: true, upsert: true }, 
                (err, res) => {

                    //do_something
                });
```

Can any one share why we have few documents are getting saved without `updated_at`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use option [**`setDefaultsOnInsert: true`**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#the-setdefaultsoninsert-option) during the `update` operation.

[**Docs**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html#the-setdefaultsoninsert-option)

> By default, mongoose only applies defaults when you create a new
>   document. It will not set defaults if you use update() and
>   findOneAndUpdate(). However, mongoose 4.x lets you opt-in to this
>   behavior using the setDefaultsOnInsert option.

```
OrderModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { order_no: orderNo },
  { $set: { items: [{ product_id: "abc", quantity: 1 }] }},
  { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }
)
```