# mongoose bulk execute create if doesnt exist, else update doesnt contain timestamps

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**EDIT:**
I am aware of `setDefaultsOnInsert` but I cant seem to figure out how to pass in that option...

```
activity.notify.forEach( user_id => {
    query = { 'notification._id': activity._id, user_id, type: "replied to an idea you're subscribed to" }
    update = { $set: { notification: activity }, $addToSet: { user_details: user_data } }
    options = { setDefaultsOnInsert: true }

    bulk.find( query ).upsert().update( update, options )
} )
```

---

Currently building out a notification system.

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
let bulk = Notification.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()

activity.notify.forEach( user_id => {
    query = { 'notification._id': activity._id, user_id, type: "replied to an idea you're subscribed to" }
    update = { $set: { notification: activity }, $addToSet: { user_details: user_data } }

    bulk.find( query ).upsert().update( update )
} )

bulk.execute()
    .then( r => console.log( 'r', r ) )
    .catch( err => console.log( 'bulk exec err ', err.writeErrors[ 0 ] ) )
```

What the code does is that it looks through an array called `notify` that contains `user_ids`.

It then looks to see if a similar notification for that said `user_id` already exists. If it does, update it with `$addToSet` to the array `user_details`.

---

The issue with this method is that it doesn't have the timestamps. Within my model, I have the line: `timestamps: true` but since I am upserting some documents, they dont go through the normal instantiation of a document with: `new Notification()`

Is there a way or method to automatically include those or do I have to create some helper functions to generate the `createdAt` and `updatedAt`

This didnt work for me

Comment: You are probably looking for [`$setDefaulOnInsert`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56140964/insert-default-values-not-working-mongodb/56141089#56141089)

Comment: @Fanpark ooo i think that is what I am looking for. EDIT: Actually... since I am using `bulk`, I dont think i can pass in options. ` bulk.find( query ).upsert().update( update )`